# Create a view including last month of a table with millions of rows

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 18000000 rows (TABLE_A). I have to execute a stored procedure every 15 minutes that selects data from the TABLE_A, make some calculations and inserts the results to another table (TABLE_B). This values of the TABLE_A comes from files that contains readings of different devices. Thus, the table will be bigger and bigger.

This is an example of the file content:

```
'2015-10-01 11:00:00.000';'par01';1
'2015-10-01 12:00:00.000';'par02';1
'2015-10-01 12:00:00.000';'par03';1
```

I think that is better to insert the new values that comes from the files to another table (TABLE_C), and make the calculations with the values of TABLE_C. I would like a query that when some variable reach one month of data, inserts the rows bigger than one month to the TABLE_A (for me one month is enough to make the calculations). Thus, with only one month of data in the TABLE_C the execution of the calculations will be faster than work with 18000000 of rows.

This is a simple example of the table:

```
DECLARE @TABLE_C(timestamp datetime, parameter char(5),  value int)
DECLARE @TABLE_A(timestamp datetime, parameter char(5),  value int)

INSERT @TABLE_C values
('2015-10-01 11:00:00.000','par01',1),
('2015-10-01 12:00:00.000','par01',1),
('2015-09-01 11:03:00.000','par01',2),
('2015-09-01 12:03:00.000','par01',2),
('2015-08-01 11:06:00.000','par01',3),
('2015-08-01 12:06:00.000','par01',3),

('2015-09-01 11:00:00.000','par02',1),
('2015-09-01 12:00:00.000','par02',1),
('2015-08-01 11:03:00.000','par02',2),
('2015-08-01 12:03:00.000','par02',2),
('2015-07-01 11:06:00.000','par02',3),
('2015-07-01 12:06:00.000','par02',3),

('2015-10-01 11:00:00.000','par03',1),
('2015-10-01 12:00:00.000','par03',1),
('2015-09-01 11:03:00.000','par03',2),
('2015-09-01 12:03:00.000','par03',2),
('2015-08-01 11:06:00.000','par03',3),
('2015-08-01 12:06:00.000','par03',3)
```

The result must be somthing like it:

```
INSERT @TABLE_C values
('2015-10-01 11:00:00.000','par01',1),
('2015-10-01 12:00:00.000','par01',1),


('2015-09-01 11:00:00.000','par02',1),
('2015-09-01 12:00:00.000','par02',1),


('2015-10-01 11:00:00.000','par03',1),
('2015-10-01 12:00:00.000','par03',1)

INSERT @TABLE_A values
('2015-09-01 11:03:00.000','par01',2),
('2015-09-01 12:03:00.000','par01',2),
('2015-08-01 11:06:00.000','par01',3),
('2015-08-01 12:06:00.000','par01',3),


('2015-08-01 11:03:00.000','par02',2),
('2015-08-01 12:03:00.000','par02',2),
('2015-07-01 11:06:00.000','par02',3),
('2015-07-01 12:06:00.000','par02',3),

('2015-09-01 11:03:00.000','par03',2),
('2015-09-01 12:03:00.000','par03',2),
('2015-08-01 11:06:00.000','par03',3),
('2015-08-01 12:06:00.000','par03',3)
```

Comment: As posted this makes no sense at all. What are you trying to do? You can't have loops or parameters in a view. This would be a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I've made some changes in the question. Do you understand better my question?

Comment: No. Your question doesn't make any sense at all. What is the logic for the result? Where does the data come from? http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx

Comment: So many rows is a challenge, only if you have to do calculations on every row again and again. If there are indexes on your parameter and your date column, it would be very fast to do a simple `BETWEEN firstDayOfMonth AND lastDayOfMonth at 23:59:59` (pseudocode)

Comment: One question: Is the last month always the same (last calendar month) or could this last month differ? In the example data all last months are october 2015...

Comment: @Shnugo the last month could be diffe. For example, for the par01 could be the september of 2015 and for the par02 could be october. I don't have to do calculations every row again and again. But a Select of 18000000 takes a lot time including where clause. I think that I could work with a table with less data (one month of data for example). Thus the selects are faster for the calculations.

Comment: @JosepBacardit, edited my answer to fit to your last comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: This is a new solution. At the beginning it will calculate the borders of the last month for each parameter and its beginning and ending. If this is fast will mainly depend on the count of different values in "parameter".

And: You need indexes!

```
SET LANGUAGE english;

DECLARE @t table(timestamp datetime, parameter char(5),  value int)

INSERT @t values
('2015-10-01 11:00:00.000','par01',1),
('2015-10-01 12:00:00.000','par01',1),
('2015-09-01 11:03:00.000','par01',2),
('2015-09-01 12:03:00.000','par01',2),
('2015-08-01 11:06:00.000','par01',3),
('2015-08-01 12:06:00.000','par01',3),

('2015-09-01 11:00:00.000','par02',1),
('2015-09-01 12:00:00.000','par02',1),
('2015-09-01 11:03:00.000','par02',2),
('2015-09-01 12:03:00.000','par02',2),
('2015-08-01 11:06:00.000','par02',3),
('2015-08-01 12:06:00.000','par02',3),

('2015-10-01 11:00:00.000','par03',1),
('2015-10-01 12:00:00.000','par03',1),
('2015-09-01 11:03:00.000','par03',2),
('2015-09-01 12:03:00.000','par03',2),
('2015-08-01 11:06:00.000','par03',3),
('2015-08-01 12:06:00.000','par03',3);

WITH MaxDates AS
(
    SELECT MAX(x.timestamp)  AS maxDate,x.parameter 
    FROM @t AS x
    GROUP BY x.parameter
)
,MonthFirst AS
(
    SELECT * 
          ,CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(YEAR(maxDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(REPLACE(STR(MONTH(maxDate),2),' ','0') AS VARCHAR(2)) + '01', 104) AS StartOfMonth
    FROM MaxDates
)
,MonthBorders AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,DATEADD(SECOND,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,StartOfMonth)) AS EndOfMonth
    FROM MonthFirst 
)
SELECT * 
FROM @t AS t
INNER JOIN MonthBorders AS mb ON t.parameter=mb.parameter AND t.timestamp BETWEEN mb.StartOfMonth AND mb.EndOfMonth
ORDER BY t.parameter;
```

One enhancement could be (saves one DATEADD):

```
WITH MaxDates AS
(
    SELECT MAX(x.timestamp)  AS maxDate,x.parameter 
    FROM @t AS x
    GROUP BY x.parameter
)
,MonthFirst AS
(
    SELECT * 
          ,CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(YEAR(maxDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(REPLACE(STR(MONTH(maxDate),2),' ','0') AS VARCHAR(2)) + '01', 104) AS StartOfMonth
    FROM MaxDates
)
,MonthBorders AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,DATEADD(MONTH,1,StartOfMonth) AS EndOfMonth
    FROM MonthFirst 
)
SELECT * 
FROM @t AS t
INNER JOIN MonthBorders AS mb ON t.parameter=mb.parameter AND t.timestamp >= mb.StartOfMonth AND t.timestamp < mb.EndOfMonth
ORDER BY t.parameter;
```

Comment: OK, you just gave the comment, that the last month is not the same for all of them... I'll edit my solution...

Comment: Hi @JosephBacardit, I edited my answer. Please be aware of the fact, that I changed the example's data so that "par02" has values in September but not in October any more. Hope this is what you need. Let's see how fast it is...

Comment: @JosepBacardit, I'm curious... Did it work? Was it fast?

Comment: Yes! It take about 20 seconds more or less.  I think that it's fast. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JosepBacardit, glad to read this! Happy coding!